Outlook Web Add In Request API problems
I am sending API request in Outlook web add-in project. But the request does not receive any return. There is no return such as Error, Success. The request did not go. Is this problem related to manifest.json or manifest.xml settings?
  const token = await API.getToken();
  console.log("Token received:", token);

  const uri = Orch.odataUrl + "/Folders";
  const url = `${uri}/UiPath.Server.Configuration.OData.GetAllRolesForUser(username='${orchSettings.usernameOrEmail}',skip=0,take=15)`;
  console.log("Sanitized URL:", url);

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-UIPATH-TenantName': orchSettings.tenantName,
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });

  console.log("Sanitized URL:", url);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("Fetch response data:", data);
  return new OrchJobs(data);


Is the Orch.odataUrl is the same as the URL where the add-on hosted?

You need to specify under what context this is running in. Is it in a taskpane or is it using smart-alerts/event based workflow? Also what Outlook client are you using (web, windows desktop)
